# How to add a Toggle Switch button in Windows Phone 8.0 application in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

How to add a Toggle Switch button in Windows Phone application in Visual Studio 2012 ?

[image: toggle switch button]

Comment: You've added tags for a bunch of Windows Phone versions. Which is it?

Comment: Windows Phone 8. Edited it for convenience :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check ToggleSwitch contained in Windows Phone Toolkit 
here 
https://phone.codeplex.com/